# How to open a section in a tabbed activity using an intent from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, sidebar

I have a Tabbed Activity with a sidebar that has 4 sections.

When I'm doing an Intent from another activity to this activity, I want it to be open on the fourth section, and not on the first section (the default).

How can I change it to be open on the fourth section?

Comment: it would be better if you placed your code here, but pseudo; code you have to pass the fourth position number to tabbed activity.

Comment: Have "another activity" pass an `Intent` extra indicating the tab that you want. Have "this activity" read that `Intent` extra (via `getIntent()`) and use that to update whatever you are using for tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

When you send an intent from another activity put a boolean bundle with that intent, when receiving intent on your activity check if bundle is true, if yes open your fourth section.

**Your sending activity**

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putBoolean("fourthSection",true);

startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this,otherActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));
```

**Your receiving activity**

```
Bundle bundle=getIntent.getExtras();
if(bundle.getBoolean("fourthSection")){
//go to your fourth section
}
```

Comment: I think passing an `int` would make it much cleaner. Passing a `boolean` requires having to handle a lot of keys. With an `int`, you could use a `TAB_INDEX` key with an appropriate value.

Comment: @LittleChild Yes, I agree with you but since the context of question was limited to fourth index I used `boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd do it:

```
public class OtherActivityThatHasYourTabs ... {
  public static final String TAB_INDEX_KEY = "tab_index";
  ...
}
```

Have a key named `TAB_INDEX_KEY`. This is how you'd get and set the tab index to be passed between these two activities.

In your "current" activity, do this:

```
Intent otherActivity = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,OtherActivityThatHasYourTabs.class);
otherActivity.putExtra(OtherActivityThatHasYourTabs.TAB_INDEX_KEY,4);
startActivity(otherActivity);
```

In your `OtherActivityThatHasYourTabs`, you can retrieve the `Intent` used to launch it via `getIntent()`.  So, you'd do this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
int tabIndex = extras.getInt(TAB_INDEX_KEY);
if( tabIndex != 0 ){
  yourMethodToDisplayTabAtIndex( tabIndex ); 
}
```

Start indexing from `1` because `getInt()` returns `0` if the key passed to `getInt()` cannot be found.

Using an `int` gives you more cleanliness and flexibility because you are only managing a single key and you can increment the index if you ever add more tabs.